# How to create a website using fluid template engine in typo3 7.6.2?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I want to create a website in typo3 7.6.2 latest version but I have no idea about typo 3.

I already installed typo3 7.6.2 to my server and also official introduction package but I don't know how to change the structure according to my requirement. Also I didn't get any proper document to create website using fluid template engine.

I read other stackoverflow question and answers but did not get the answer to my question.

Thanks

Comment: I added an answer to your question, but as a sidenote: Stackoverflow is intended für specific questions to programming problems, not general questions like this one. Just FYI that these kind of questions will most likely be downvoted and closed quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some of extension available in [TER](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/) and can use 
[FTM](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ftm/) Or [MASK](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mask/) , these extension have good documentation as well as well structured for the new version of TYPO3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no short answer to your question. TYPO3 is no easy system, it has a complex templating engine with a multitude of options.

What you need is extensive training for TYPO3 templating, fluid, typoscript etc. A good place to start with that is in the TYPO3 documentation center: http://typo3.org/documentation/

More specifically you might want to take a look at TYPO3 templating for beginners articles, like this one in the wiki: https://wiki.typo3.org/Templating_Tutorial_-_Basics

Comment: Thanks for reply.


 I installed official introduction package, just want to know that how to change the frontend structure according to our need? I need to add one more top menu to the header so how can I change or add another top menu to it?

Answer (score 0):

Any short code examples for using FLUIDTEMPLATE:

- [Typoscript object FLUIDTEMPLATE](http://www.welovetypo3.com/wiki/fluidtemplate-1/)
- [Fluidtemplate 2: Page layout change](http://www.welovetypo3.com/wiki/fluidtemplate-2/)
- [Fluidtemplate 3: Using bootstrap template](http://www.welovetypo3.com/wiki/fluidtemplate-using-bootstrap-template/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the "FluidTYPO3 site kickstarter" extension (extension key: `site`). It is a distribution - installing it and allowing it to run will result in a new extension being generated for you with some default template files inside it; and your site being configured to display these templates.

It should take less than a minute from install until you're editing templates.